# Shorter admin url for options page

Tags: theme-options

Is it possible to create a short admin url for options page?

The default admin url is:

domain.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=options-page-slug

And i want it to be:
domain/wp-admin/options-page-slug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean, `wp-admin/admin.php?page=options-page-slug`?

But yes, you can use [the rewrite API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule#Using_rewrite_rules_to_redirect_to_scripts_other_than_index.php):

```php
add_action( 'init', function () {
    // The following adds the rule into the database.
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'wp-admin/options-page-slug(/|$)',
        'wp-admin/admin.php?page=options-page-slug',
        'top'
    );
} );
```

Or alternatively, just add this before the WordPress rules in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^wp-admin/options-page-slug(/|$) /wp-admin/admin.php?page=options-page-slug [QSA,L]
```